# Excel Formula to get the values

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking for excel formula to get the values next to color. For example, if this is paste in column the color value will show on column b (sage)

For an alluring and contemporary update for your home

**Product Features :**

- Brand : L Linens
- Color : Sage
- Material : Cotton
- Size : California King
- Type : Bed Sheets
- Pattern : Solid
- Deep pocket Fitted Sheet with elastic all around designed to fit extra thick mattresses

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have written so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

1) You would need to define a list of colour names and their corresponding colour codes. Lets assume you create a table of colours and their code on a sheet called "Colour Index" and you placed the Colour Names in Column A and their colour value in Column B.  We will also assume that you used a single header row so your data starts in row 2.  (note colour values are completely fictious)

```
       (A)      (B)
       Colour
(1)    Name     Value
(2)    Red      145
(3)    Orange    13
(4)    Yellow     3
(5)    Green    177
(6)    Blue     156
(7)    Indigo   250
(8)    Violet    67
```

The problem with building the colour table, is that there is a potential of 16777216 colours out there depending on how you define colours.  So lets say there is a measly 256 shades of red.  Which one of those reds is red, which is fire engine red and which is blood red, etc.  While defining a colour with a number can be very exact, people's interpretation of what colour corresponds to a number can be highly subjective.

2)  You could then in your original sheet in column B use the following formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND(":",B3))),'Colour Index'!$A$2:$B$7,2,0),"")
```

The IFERROR returns "" to make the cell look empty if your colour name in B3 is not found.

The RIGHT functions pulls the right characters in the name after the ":"

The TRIM is there to eliminate the leading space since I was not sure how many spaces there would be.

The VLOOKUP looks for the name from the right function in your colour table and if found returns to value in the second column of the search table.

FIND determines the position of the : within the text in B3

LEN counts the number of characters in the text in B3